# NFA or DFA for strings the contain exactly twice substring ab?

Tags: automata

Given the language with alphabet: {a, b, c} Draw an NFA or DFA for all the strings that have exactly twice substrings "ab" and at least on "c". I'm stuck with "exactly twice "ab"". Can somebody give me some ideas. It's also very good if you can suggest me the regular expression of this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this covers it, but you should verify.
[image: DFA picture]

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Your solution are the same to me! Although it look a bit complicated but I think it's the correct one!

Comment: BTW, do you use any special program to draw this Automaton @ben rudgers

Comment: I drew it up in a CAD program. I started on paper. But now I would use jFlap. It is a free Java application available at jflap.org. The shape is ugly because I removed redundant states, and I was too lazy to re-organize it neatly.

Comment: I used to use JFLAP, it's an excellent program for Grammar and Other things related to Compiler Design,etc. However, I don't like the style of its shapes very much, so I think I will use LaTeX though it's a bit time-consuming

Comment: InkScape is an alternative for creating drawings of Automata [rather than modeling Automata]. InkScape uses SVG as a native format, but outputs to LaTeX (It is a `SaveAs` option, but I have not used it).